Alignment issues and inserting text in the same line
I've recently jumped into the TeX bandwagon and looking forward to learn more as I dig deeper.
I am making a standard letter format for my company and would like the following at the beginning of the letter.
Courtesy : MS Word
However, when I am trying to do the same in LaTeX, I get this.

My question is : How can I get the date aligned with the address? I have tried to insert the Ref/Date line into the table, but then it does not expand the entire page.  I have gone through various solutions in the forums, but haven't got a suitable solution.
My code :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1in,   bottom=1in, left=1in,   right=1in, ]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l @{}}
    XXX \\
    Address 1 \\ 
    Address 2 \\
    Phone: (000) 111-1111 \\
    Email: xxx@example.com \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip 
File ref : XXXX \hfill
\today \\ 


\end{document}

Thanks a lot!
Praveen

Typeset it inside the table.

Off-topic: The margin options top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in, may be expressed more succinctly as margin=1in.

Use a bottom aligned tabular:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  top=1in,
  bottom=1in,
  left=1in,
  right=1in,
]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent
File ref : XXXX\hfill
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
    XXX \\
    Address 1 \\
    Address 2 \\
    Phone: (000) 111-1111 \\
    Email: xxx@example.com \\[4ex]
\today \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


You might be interested in a different and easier input style.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  top=1in,
  bottom=1in,
  left=1in,
  right=1in,
]{geometry}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\letterhead}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { praven/letterhead } {#1}
  \praven_letterhead_make:
 }

\keys_define:nn { praven/letterhead }
 {
  ref       .tl_set:N  = \l__praven_letterhead_fileref_tl,
  addressee .tl_set:N  = \l__praven_letterhead_addressee_tl,
  phone     .tl_set:N  = \l__praven_letterhead_phone_tl,
  email     .tl_set:N  = \l__praven_letterhead_email_tl,
  date      .tl_set:N  = \l__praven_letterhead_date_tl,
  date      .initial:n = \today,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \praven_letterhead_make:
 {
  \par\noindent
  ref:~\l__praven_letterhead_fileref_tl
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
  \l__praven_letterhead_addressee_tl \\
  Phone:~\l__praven_letterhead_phone_tl \\
  Email:~\texttt{\l__praven_letterhead_email_tl} \\[4ex]
  \l__praven_letterhead_date_tl
  \end{tabular}
  \bigskip
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% first example

\letterhead{
  ref=XXXX,
  addressee= XXX \\ Address 1 \\ Address 2,
  phone=(000) 111-1111,
  email=xxx@example.com,
}

% second example

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip

\letterhead{
  ref = YYYYY,
  addressee= {YYY \\ Address 1 \\ Address 2 \\ Address 3},
  phone = (000) 111-1111,
  email = xxx@example.com,
  date = {December 31, 2024}
}

\end{document}

The keys can be given in any order. The date key is optional and, if not specified as in the first example, defaults to \today.
Complex values, such as addressee and date are better braced.


Thanks a lot.  Good options, will definitely explore these options. The second option looks more inviting since it will allow me to design my letterheads for every occasion!

As @daleif has already suggested in a comment, just place the address information, the file reference, and the date in two-column table. I suggest you use a tabularx environment and set its target width to \textdwidth.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' environment and 'X' column type
\usepackage{parskip}  % no paragraph indentation

\usepackage{newtx}    % optional: Times Roman font

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X l @{}}
& XXX \\
& Address 1 \\ 
& Address 2 \\
& Phone: (000) 111-1111 \\
& Email: xxx@example.com \\[1cm]
File ref : XXXX & \today
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}


Thanks.  Your comment on the margins also noted.

Not sure a tabular is required. You could use a minipage, with [b] to align the baseline of its last line with the baseline of the surrounding
File ref : XXXX
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    XXX \par
    Address 1 \par
    Address 2 \par
    Phone: (000) 111-1111 \par
    Email: xxx@example.com \par
    \bigskip
    \today
\end{minipage}

Use two minipage if you need to add more content to the lef side. Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
  File ref: XXXX\\
  Other ref: YYYY
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    XXX \par
    Address 1 \par
    Address 2 \par
    Phone: (000) 111-1111 \par
    Email: xxx@example.com \par
    \bigskip
    \today
\end{minipage}

\end{document}



I'm still new to TeX.  Have come across the option for minipage for the first time. I don't (yet) understand the nuances of using linewidth much.  That being said, would this be a better option than using Tabular, since I find that a simpler solution for my requirement.

A minipage is just a box, inside which you can insert paragraphs. The mandatory argument, between {...}is its width (see for example [latexref](https://latexref.xyz/fr/minipage.html)). I used\linewidth to make the right box width 50% of the line width. But you can replace it with any length, like5cm`.

Alright got that. So technically, if I make three minipages of appropriate sizes, then using the [b]/[t] align, I can get them to be in line? I'm still trying to design my letterheads.  The aim is to use a logo, left box and right box.

@PraveenKumar Experiment. You don't need a minipage if your logo is just a \includegraphics{...}. minipage are only relevant if you have many lines.
